# Different behavior between sed versions

Tags: bash, sed

So, I'm working on a bash script that will run on a server. The problem is that the same command produces different results, depending on where I run it.

The input:

```
Theme Name: My Theme
```

The command:

```
sed -e '/^Theme Name:/s/$/ (nightly)/' style.css
```

The output (local machine, sed 4.2.1):

```
Theme Name: My Theme (nightly)
```

The output (server, sed 4.1.5):

```
 (nightly): My Theme
```

What gives?

PS: I tried using awk's `sub()` function, with similar results.

Comment: I don't see any reason in your example to use dbl-quotes. Maybe the $ is screwing something up. Try using single-quotes for your sed cmd? Also, I would say your 4.2.1 output is correct, right :-? Finally, wrong output that you show looks like you're executing a command like '/^Theme Name:/s// (nightly)'. (Ah defintely the $ and dbl-quotes).Turn on `set -vx` to see what is happening with that line. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Thanks, but that didn't help. Yes, the 4.2.1 output is the expected one.

Comment: @shellter: Huh, didn't know about `set -vx`. Still, the `$` doesn't seem to be the problem. Probably a bug in some common regex library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the style.css file has windows-style line endings on the server. The `\r` character is sending the cursor back to the beginning of the line. Try using `dos2unix` on the file on your server.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what happened.

Comment: I hate dos2unix, it overwrites the files. Instead I always use `tr -d \\r` which is available on all systems and can be used as a filter and simply removes the `\r` characters.